# Devo usar foreign_key tanto em has_many quanto em belongs_to?

Tags: banco-de-dados, ruby-on-rails, active-record, chave-estrangeira

Eu tenho dois models. Office e Employee. Employee tem office_id como chave estrangeira. Então, qual é o correto?

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees, foreign_key: 'office_id' 
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office, foreign_key: 'office_id'
end
```

Ou

```
class Office < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :office, foreign_key: 'office_id'
end
```

Eu acho que o segundo exemplo é o correto, porque pra mim, não faz sentido declarar o `foreign_key` no `has_many`. Um colega de trabalho discorda, e acredita que o primeiro exemplo é o correto, sendo que a chave estrangeira deve ser declarada em ambos os lados da relação. Eu não encontrei muitas referências a esse assunto. Então, alguém sabe me dizer qual dos dois está correto e o porquê?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2º opção é a correta, como você mesmo disse é a sua classe Employee que possue a chave estrangeira na relação. Você também pode omitir a colocação da foreign_key na sua classe Employee, porque por padrão ele usa o nome da associação seguido do sufixo _id.

De acordo com a documentação:

> :foreign_key Specify the foreign key used for the association. By
>   default this is guessed to be the name of the association with an
>   “_id” suffix. So a class that defines a belongs_to :person association
>   will use “person_id” as the default :foreign_key.

[belongs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to)